# How to insert data in to database when mail comes in inbox(mail server)

Tags: email, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a requirement. I have a mail server where user sends mail with there requirement and i need to insert data in my database when mail arrive in mail box. i Have no idea about it. If anybody has any idea please share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below codes for sending and receiving mails accordingly:

Send Mail

```
var message = new MailMessage("admin@bendytree.com", "someone@example.com");
message.Subject = "What Up, Dog?";
message.Body = "Why you gotta be all up in my grill?";`enter code here`
SmtpClient mailer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
mailer.Credentials = new  NetworkCredential("admin@bendytree.com","YourPasswordHere");
mailer.EnableSsl = true;
mailer.Send(message);
```

Recieving Mail

```
client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
client.Authenticate("admin@bendytree.com", "YourPasswordHere");
var count = client.GetMessageCount();
Message message = client.GetMessage(count);
Console.WriteLine(message.Headers.Subject);
```

You can use this message object for database insertion.